# Google Maps API Map Click Event doesn't work when clicked on an overlay geojson layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I've implemented a click event on the map using

`google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', mapclick);`

and everything is working fine.

I've also added a geojson layer on map. So, the problem is when I click on the overlay geojson layer (which is a polygon layer actually), the map click event not fired. Hence, my question is what should I do so that map click event also work when I click on an overlay layer on map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "geojson layer" , but when you mean a [Data-layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#data_layer_events) there are 2 options:

1. **when you don't need the click-event to be triggered for the feature(e.g. polygon)**
    set the clickable-option of the layer to false:

   ```
     map.data.setStyle({clickable:false});
   ```
2. **when the click-event should be triggered for both, map and feature**
     trigger the event for the map programmatically:

   ```
      map.data.addListener('click',function(e){
        google.maps.event.trigger(this.getMap(),'click',e);
      });
   ```